# How to calculate the angle between these rectangles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to make a seating area similar to the following shape with three rectangles of equal length ($l$) and width ($w$), where the green rectangle makes an angle ($\theta$) with the blue rectangle. While, the red rectangle makes an angle ($\phi$) with the blue rectangle. I know that the length of the small arc $c_1=\alpha\, c_2$, where $c_2$ is the length of the bigger arc and $\alpha>0$. How does the angle ($\theta$) change as I change the value of $\alpha$?

[image]

Comment: you rectangles have two arc length upper side and lower side, what are your angles ?Pleas add them in the picture. It is not clear what c1 and c2 are. do you measure the angles in radians or degree?

Comment: @trula, the photoediter I used doesn't allow latex, but $c_2$ is the lower arc with angle $\theta$ and $c_1$ is the upper arc with angle $(\phi-\theta)$.

Comment: Do you mean the length of an arc not covered by rectangles? What is the radius of the circle? What role can the length of a rectangle play?

Comment: I suppose you measure the angle between the middle lines of the rectangle than the arc length $c_2=R\cdot \Theta; c_1=R\cdot (\Phi-\Theta)$ if you measure the angles in radians. $\text{Angle in radians=angle in degree }\cdot \frac{\pi}{180}$ I still do not understand what your  is, but with these arc length you should be able to calculate everything you need